# iOS 7 - wake iPhone from proximity sleep

Tags: ios, iphone

When I enable proximity monitoring with

```
[UIDevice currentDevice].proximityMonitoringEnabled = YES;
```

I can turn off the screen by covering proximity sensor with something. However setting `proximityMonitoringEnabled` to `NO` does not turn screen back on until cover is removed from sensor.

How can I wake iPhone from 'proximity sleep' programmatically without removing sensor cover?

So far I've tried the following right after disabling proximity monitoring (which have not helped):

- opening another application via URL scheme
- firing local notification
- setting `[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled` to `YES`/`NO`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do that on iOS 7 is to use private API, which is protected by entitlements. A mere mortal developers cannot do that on non-jailbroken device.